# How do I combine a group of circles and open paths to make one shape in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

[image: My workspace]
I am trying to create a clubs symbol for some cards I am designing, but I do not know how to combine closed shapes with open paths. I know how to use pathfinder to combine closed shapes but that does not work for this.

Comment: @go-junta I feel like that isn't a good dupe. There are [several others](https://www.google.com/search?q=combine+paths+illustrator+graphicdesign&oq=combine+paths+illustrator+graphicdesign&aqs=chrome..69i57.4864j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) though

Answer (score 2):

The shape builder tool will do this -

- https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html